# Isomorphism between $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ and $V : X^{2} + Y^{2} = pZ^{2}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

My question is about an exercise from "arithmetic of elliptic curves":

Let $$ V : X^{2} + Y^{2} = pZ^{2}$$ be a projective vareity in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $p$ be a prime number.

prove that $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ iff $ p \equiv 1$(mod $4$).

and for $p \equiv 3$(mod $4$) no two of such vareities are isomorphic.

---

I was trying to solve this exercise but I have stuck in defining the morphism. And as it is the case that $p \equiv 1$(mod $4$) I think we should use an integer solution of $a^{2} + b^{2} =p$. but most of my efforts didn't turn out to be a morphism. So if anyone could help with this, it would be great.

Comment: When $p\equiv1\pmod 4$ the conic has a rational point. You can then use the usual tricks to transform it into standard form.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown could you explain a little bit more about the process?